# EJB vs Rmi comparison

Tags: ejb

On higher level if we analyze EJB say statelessEJB Bean , its seems to be that ejb framework created out of RMI API's.
 Reason why i am saying this :-

IN RMI also ae have remote interface. on naming lookup we get the stub which gives a call to skelton which internally calls to remote object.

In EJB we have home interface  and remote interface whose implementation are provided by ejb container( which looks like nothing but stubs)
on calling create on home interface it gives the remote object on which as per me will give the call to skelton which internally calls the session 
object.

Please let me know if above comparison makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the EJB specification has always required RMI compatibility (and some application servers are built on top of CORBA).  Prior to EJB 3.0, remote EJBs were required to have component interface that extends EJBObject (thus java.rmi.Remote), and all methods were required to throw java.rmi.RemoteException.  In fact, local interfaces didn't exist in earlier specification versions.  The EJB specification attempted to simplify RMI by allowing a container to manage the lifecycle and scalability of remote objects.  (Of course, it also had other non-remoting goals.)

Comment: one more question on this? Say we call some method doDeposit(AccountInfo accInfo) on remote object. Does stub internally write the accInfo to some File using objectOutPutStream and then transmit it over network. Is It Correct? Is file the only way to transmit the any java object over network?

Comment: If the remote object is in the same JVM, the stub will do some optimizations to "copy" the object (assuming that AccountInfo is serializable and not also Remote).  Otherwise, the object will be "marshalled" (serialized) to write over a socket, and then "unmarshalled" (deserialized) on the receiving JVM.  The file system should not be directly involved.

Comment: Small note that there is no actual RMI requirement in the EJB spec in a direct sense.  The actual requirement is that applications must be written to be RMI "compatible".  Some vendors like WebLogic and OpenEJB have their own client/server protocols.  Some like WebSphere exclusively use CORBA.